# Create DropDowns that are based on which criteria are searched for

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-sheets, formula, path-dependent-type

I am trying to allow the user to search on any of 4 criteria and have the rest of the 3 remaining field data validate based on the first search for selection.

I have four fields that I am trying to make dependent drop downs for the remaining 3 based on what you search for 1st.  For example:
Scenario 1 - I search the data range validation for NAME and select a name in Cell L2.

I want the Phone, Email and Address to become dependent on the name was chosen (as there may be multiple records with the name of the person chosen).
I have accomplished this by using a secondary filter formula to filter address based on the name chosen and then applied data validation from the filter.

My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to do the same thing if they pick the address first.  Because my data validation is set on the filtered values and not the entire database.  If they picked the address first, I want to validate based on ALL addresses and then filter-validate the NAME, PHONE and EMAIL.

I really just want them to be able to search whatever of the 4 criteria and then validate the other 3 on that result.

Any thoughts would help.
You can see my formula for filtering Addresses based on the Name selection in Cell S2 of the Customer Record Tab.

```
=if(L6="Address",filter('Sample Data'!$C:$C,'Sample Data'!$E:$E=L6),IF(L6="Phone",filter('Sample Data'!$C:$C,'Sample Data'!$D:$D=L3),IF(L6="Email",filter('Sample Data'!$C:$C,'Sample Data'!$J:$J=L4),L2)))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E7adi88aEgvdV4ao8unbMHgZLEyu5CCRdTOjv8thjtc/edit#gid=1427488050

---

Select Name and only the Phones, Emails and Addresses for that selected name can be selected.
Select the Address and only the Names, Phones and Emails for that Address can be selected.
Same for Phone and for Email

Comment: so you wanna like narrow it down the search with each selection?

Comment: Yes.  But the selections could come in any order.  If there were always,name then address, then email, then phone, I would be fine.  But sometimes the order will change to address, then name, then phone, then email.  This is where I am stuck

Comment: well, I imagine 4 helper columns each with 4 IFs covering 16 possible scenarios